# smooth scroll not working on safari browser when using nextjs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, smooth-scrolling

what am trying to achieve is the scroll behaviour: smooth but on safari, when clicking a link in the menu, all browsers will smoothly go the the section that the link refer to except for safari it will jump to section immediately, I tried every single option to achieve this (react-scroll, smooth-scroll, smoothScroll polyfill) nothing works, everyone referring to smooth scroll polyfill but its not working, there is no error it just do nothing.
I put it inside use effect and other options, I also tried to removed the  "window.**forceSmoothScrollPolyfill** = true;" also not working.

am I doing something wrong here?

```
import smoothscroll from 'smoothscroll-polyfill';


if (typeof window !== undefined) {
  console.log('polyfilled');
  smoothscroll.polyfill();
  window.__forceSmoothScrollPolyfill__ = true;
}
```

Comment: are you sure? Because this is what am seeing in the documentation :
Successfully working in:

natively supported in Chrome
natively supported in Firefox
Safari 6+
Internet Explorer 9+
Microsoft Edge 12+
Opera Next

Comment: You're right, somehow I ended up on an older version of the package

Comment: Where are you running this piece of code?

Comment: well I tried both on the page directly in the index.js and on the app.js both didn't work

Comment: inside `useEffect()`, right?

Comment: yep inside useEffect and outside it, and also tried this Package  "smoothscroll-anchor-polyfill" but still nothing!!